# How to ignore folders with cpplint

Tags: c++, cpplint

How do you tell [cpplint](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint) to ignore folders of a specific name?

I have `.build` folders that contain auto-generated files, and when I run `cpplint --recursive src` it traverses these folders and finds a tons of errors I don't care about.

I've tried using the `--exclude` parameter, like:

```
cpplint --recursive --exclude=.build src
```

but that has no effect.

I've also tried:

```
cpplint --recursive --exclude=*/.build src
```

and other variations that use wildcards, but those also have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
./cpplint.py \
    $( find . -name \*.h -or -name \*.cc | grep -vE "^\.\/<excluded_folder_name>\/" )
```

You can make use of this argument along with your cpplint command:

```
find $PWD -not \( -path $PWD/<folder1> -prune \) -not \( -path $PWD/<folder2> -prune \) -not \( -path $PWD/<folder3> -prune \) -name *.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

To run recursively on all sub-folders and not to check specific folders or files, first parameter should be whet to exclude from recursive check and only after that to enable recursion.

I am using the following command:

```
cpplint --exclude=./src/autogenerated --recursive ./src/ > /dev/null 2> ./codestyle.log
```

In mycase, `cpplint` will run in all `./src` folder recursively but will omit `./src/autogenerated dir`
all stdout will be redirected to /dev/null trash, and all errors that i want to fix will be redirected to my log file `./codestyle.log`

Comment: I got this error:FATAL ERROR: Invalid arguments: option --exlude not recognized

Comment: You right, my mistake, it should be --exclude="folder/path", thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
cpplint --exclude=fold/ * --exclude=fold/ * / * --exclude=fold/ * / * / * 
   exam.c
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24068119).